# Convert image/jpeg from GET request to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, http, get, uiimage

I have some restrictions and can't use native serializers or Alamofire. I have only response with body (coded image) and Content-Type = image/jpeg. This code didn't work:

```
let responseString = response as! String
let data = NSData(bytes: responseString, length: responseString.characters.count)
let image = UIImage(data: data, scale: 1.0) // nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response will itself be an NSData directly try

```
var image = UIImage(data: response, scale: 1.0)
```